# NASM Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

So, I want to create a program that allows user to enter matrix 4x5. I declared "pointers" to specific rows and "pointer" to these pointers in order to have an access to every string using one pointer. I have created strings because I want to check symbols in these strings (user can enter only numbers and + or - as the first symbol). So I have a problem when I check the first symbol (this one should be + or -) and if user does not enter + or - I see  Segmentation fault (core dumped). I use Ubuntu. (English is not my native language and if I made a mistake just do not worry about that))).

```
; Task: write a program that allows to enter 2-D array 4x5. Show only 2 first columns.
;   # # # # #  
;   # # # # #
;   # # # # #
;   # # # # # 


section .bss ; The section intended for uninitilizated data
    string_00 resb 7
    string_01 resb 7
    string_02 resb 7
    string_03 resb 7
    string_04 resb 7

    string_10 resb 7
    string_11 resb 7
    string_12 resb 7
    string_13 resb 7
    string_14 resb 7

    string_20 resb 7
    string_21 resb 7
    string_22 resb 7
    string_23 resb 7
    string_24 resb 7

    string_30 resb 7
    string_31 resb 7
    string_32 resb 7
    string_33 resb 7
    string_34 resb 7

section .data ; The section designed for using initilizated data
    GreenColor db 0x1b, '[32m' ; The string that can change text color to green
    lenGreenColor equ $ - GreenColor ; The lenth of this string

    RedColor db 0x1b, '[31m' ; The string that can change text color to red (used if user will enter incorrect data)
    lenRedColor equ $ - RedColor ; The lenth of this string

    Task db 'This program allows you to enter matrix 4x5 and show only 2 first colums.', 0xa ; Just a string that shows my task
    lenTask equ $ - Task ; The lenth of this string

    Warning db 'Enter 16-bit numbers (from -32767 to +32768) and enter the sign of number, please.', 0xa ; Warning, I chose 16-bit number because the bigger
    lenWarning equ $ - Warning ; The lenth of this string                                                ; numbers will be processed in the same way, but long
                                                                                                         ; numbers are not necessary    

    ErrorSign db 'You should use the sign of the number ( + or - )!', 0xa ; An error message to user if he did not use the number sign
    lenErrorSing equ $ - ErrorSign ; THe lenth of this message

    pointer_0 dd string_00, string_01, string_02, string_03, string_04
    pointer_1 dd string_10, string_11, string_12, string_13, string_14
    pointer_2 dd string_20, string_21, string_22, string_23, string_24
    pointer_3 dd string_30, string_31, string_32, string_33, string_34

    pointer dd pointer_0, pointer_1, pointer_2, pointer_3

    external_counter db 0
    internal_counter db 0

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov edx, lenGreenColor
    mov ecx, GreenColor
    call _print

    mov edx, lenTask
    mov ecx, Task
    call _print

    mov edx, lenWarning
    mov ecx, Warning
    call _print

    call _check



    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

_print:
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80
    ret

_enter:
    mov edx, 7
    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 3
    int 0x80
    ret

_check:
    external_loop:
        mov eax, [pointer]
        mov ebx, [external_counter]
        mov esi, [eax + ebx * 4]

            internal_loop:
                mov ebx, [internal_counter]

                add ebx, ebx
                add ebx, ebx
                add ebx, ebx

                add esi, ebx
                mov ecx, esi
                call _enter

                cmp [esi], byte 43
                je norm_sign
                cmp [esi], byte 45
                je norm_sign


                xor esi, esi
                xor eax, eax
                xor ebx, ebx
                xor ecx, ecx
                xor edx, edx


                jmp _check
                    norm_sign:
                        ret
```

Comment: At the first try I can enter number and if I entered number without + or - the program have to go to the start of function and makes the same commands, but it is an error

Comment: Code that you've posted seems incomplete. It never calls `_enter`, it never loops to labels `external_loop` and `internal_loop`. I suggest to signalize input error with carry-flag returned from `_check` and branch the main thread adequately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `mov ebx, [external_counter]` but also `external_counter db 0`. Since `ebx` is a 32-bit register, that's going to read 4 bytes from `external_counter`. The problem is `external_counter` is only 1 byte long. That means you're going to pull 3 garbage bytes into `ebx`, which will send you way out of range when you do `mov esi, [eax + ebx * 4]`. Do `external_counter dd 0` instead. (And it looks like you make the same mistake with `internal_counter` too.)

Comment: Super! Thanks! But I do not understand why when I enter a number at the first time it is OK, but at the second time is an error? I have used xor to clear registers...

Comment: @Danny When your program first started, the "garbage bytes" were probably 0, so things worked by happenstance. After you read the first entry, they had gotten used for something, thus breaking the next iteration.

Comment: @Danny: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has links to docs (including the NASM manual, but more importantly to Intel's x86 manuals / instruction-set reference).  Also, use a debugger so you can see what's wrong (like EBX holding a huge value) for yourself.